# Dynamically generated code-behind button won't fire its event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a series of controls (3 labels, 3 text boxes, and 2 buttons) that are created when the user clicks a button on my page. The page does its postback with the commands that will generate these controls. However, when I fill in my textboxes and click one of the newly generated buttons (`btnCreate`), nothing happens, and the page just reloads once again.

What I want to happen is that when the user clicks `btnCreate`, it fires its function, and puts the `TextBox.Text` into a database. But again, when `btnCreate` is clicked, nothing happens.

Here is the code for the generated buttons (It's the same function that generates the text boxes, which I've excluded here):

```
Protected Sub createSpecialNotes()
    Dim btnCreate As Button = New Button
    Dim btnClear As Button = New Button

    'Place properties

    lblSubject.Text = "subject"
    lblSubject.ID = "lblSubject"
    lblSubject.Width = 700
    lblAgenda.Text = "Agenda Note"
    lblAgenda.ID = "lblAgenda"
    lblAgenda.Width = 700
    lblMinutes.Text = "Minutes Note"
    lblMinutes.ID = "lblMinutes"
    lblMinutes.Width = 700

    btnCreate.Text = "Create"
    btnCreate.ID = "btnCreate"
    btnClear.Text = "Clear"
    btnClear.ID = "btnClear"

    'Add handlers for buttons
    AddHandler btnCreate.Click, AddressOf btnCreate_Click
    AddHandler btnClear.Click, AddressOf btnClear_Click

    plhCreateSpecialNotes.Controls.Add(btnCreate)
    plhCreateSpecialNotes.Controls.Add(btnClear)
End Sub
```

And for the sake of simplicity, let's just say `btnCreate` needs only to display the textboxes' contents.

**Edit1:** The call for create special notes is on page_preInit. It's call consists of the following

```
    Protected Sub Page_PreInit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
    'Find the control that was fired
    Dim controlFired As Control = GetPostBackControl(Me.Page)

    If (controlFired IsNot Nothing) Then
        If (controlFired.ClientID.ToString() = "btnCreateSpecial") Then
            Call createSpecialNotes()
        End If
        If (controlFired.ClientID.ToString() = "btnCreate") Then
            'i've tried putting things here to no avail.
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The function getpostbackcontrol looks like this

```
    Public Shared Function GetPostBackControl(ByVal thePage As Page) As Control
    Dim myControl As Control = Nothing
    Dim ctrlName As String = thePage.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET")
    If ((ctrlName IsNot Nothing) And (ctrlName <> String.Empty)) Then
        myControl = thePage.FindControl(ctrlName)
    Else
        For Each Item As String In thePage.Request.Form
            Dim c As Control = thePage.FindControl(Item)
            If (TypeOf (c) Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button) Then
                myControl = c
            End If
        Next

    End If
    Return myControl
End Function
```

I hope this helps to clear things up as to why I'm having trouble.

Comment: Code tip: `Dim (something) As Button = New Button` can be rewritten as `Dim (something) As New Button`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would be really useful here is to know when you're calling `createSpecialNotes()`. But most probably what you are missing is the life-cycle of the page.

Make sure `createSpecialNotes()` is called `OnInit` of your page. Anything after that is too late and your event handler won't be fired.

If `OnLoad` of your page is reached and you haven't yet bound the handler to your control, then it won't be fired.

I recommend that you read this article carefully. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: Even on postback you musst add dynamic controls at init event.

Comment: createSpecialNotes() works fine. Everything comes up properly, and is displayed as soon as I click the button that calls it.

It's called on Page_PreInit. The problem really is when I click btnCreate, nothing happens.

Comment: addendum: So I uploaded a picture of what im looking at [here](http://i.imgur.com/pcJ4w.jpg). What I highlighted is the problem. That button needs too enter the textbox.text data into the database. But again, once I click it, nothing at all happens.

Comment: @user1066300 You have to call `createSpecialNotes()` before you can access anything created by it, for example 'if controlFired.ClientID.ToString() = "btnCreate"...' cannot work until you've called `createSpecialNotes()`.

Comment: But how do i know to call it on my preinit, if my ControlFired variable is empty, as it is when I first click create?

Comment: addendum: I've tried adding an createSpecialNotes() call as the first thing in my page_preInit, to have it all built before looking to see if btncreate was clicked. And it still comes up with controlFired = nothing

Comment: Hey, I figured things out, Thanks for the help guys. I've sort of figured things out here. I know I have to call my createSpecialNotes() before hand so the button is allready created. But now I just have to figure out how to NOT display the createSpecialNotes method unless I call it first! Anyway, Thanks again, I can figure out my way from here probably.